# Unable to Edit Record with Foreign Key Relationship in ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm encountering an issue in my ASP.NET Core MVC application where I'm unable to edit records in a table that has a foreign key relationship with another table but however when i edit a record in a table that has no foreign key relationship with another table i can able to edit it. why is that? i hope you can help me. thanks you in so much
.
This is my UserController Code for editing a record:

```
 public IActionResult EditUserAccount(User obj)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         _db.User.Update(obj);
         _db.SaveChanges();

         return RedirectToAction("ManageUserAccount");
     }
     return View();
 }
```

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: There's no error showing... Its just when i edit a record in a table and that table has a foreign key referencing from another table is i cant edit that record from that table.

Comment: I try to edit a record in a user table with a foreign key(LocationID) referencing from location table(LocationID). But i cant able to edit. but when i try editing other tables withoud any foreign key i can able to edit the record..